# Regarding LDAP Search Query

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

Let's suppose that I want to search a number say `123` and LDAP has entries like `123#` or `1-2-3`. What should be the LDAP Search filter which needs to be provided? I tried `*123*` but it doesn't work in case of `1-2-3`.

Answer (score 3):

LDAP does not have "entries like 123#", it has entries identified by distinguished names that contain attributes. To search for an an entry that contains a value, you must provide the following parameters to a search request:

- base object (distinguished name where the search should commence)
- scope - base, one level subordinate to the base, or subtree (all entries subordinate to the base object
- filter - an assertion that must evaluate to true in order for the entry to be returned to the client
- attributes to return - a list of attributes that the LDAP client desires

If the attribute in question is named `number` and has a syntax of Integer and a matching rule of IntegerMatch, then the filter `(number=123)` will find an attribute named `number` with the integer value of `123`. Which filter to use depends on the syntax and matching rule in the attribute type definition because the directory server performs the task of matching attribute values against provided filters with matching rules (as must applications, by the way). Programmers must not consider LDAP attribute values to be "strings", instead they must understand attribute syntaxes and matching rules. There is a `DirectoryString` syntax (with a very specific definition, though for many purposes it can be considered a garden-variety string) but not all attributes are defined with `DirectoryString` syntax. Nor do all attributes use the same matching rules and ordering rules.

#### see also

- [LDAP: ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)
- [LDAP: Mastering search filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Comment: my requirement is very simple.

Input string is dynamic.

Lets say 123 is the input string and DB has 10203 , 19293 , 1-2-3 , 123 . Then Search should return only 1-2-3 and 123. Since it contains 1-2-3 i dont think IntegerMatch is the way to go about it!

The only thing which is fixed here is that the input will always be numbers and db will also contain numbers only.

I tried using approx(id ~= 123) but it returns all the 4 entries in db.Maybe i need to add an extra filter to it with & to filter it down further..Any ideas?

Comment: If your attribute has DirectoryString syntax, you might try a substring filter assertion, for example (|(attributename=*123)(attributeName=*1-2-3*))